# Else If Statement Swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to build an if/then basic app that will display the federal income tax for the values input in the .swift file in the label once the button is pressed. I'm planning on making the code more functional later, but wanted to test what I have. The only problem is, when I press the button, it shows 0.0, when it should be around 40...does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBAction func ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    var hourly:Float = 8.00
    var hours:Float = 61.75
    var exemptions:Float = 1.00
    var deductions:Float = 95.80
    var allowances:Float = (exemptions * deductions)
    var gross:Float = (hourly * hours)
    var taxable:Float = (gross - allowances)
    if taxable >= 17529 {
        var fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.396) + 5062.69)}
    else if taxable < 17529 && taxable >= 17458  {
        var fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.35) + 5037.84)}
    else if taxable < 17458 && taxable >= 8081  {
        var fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.33) + 1943.43)}
    else if taxable < 8081 && taxable >= 3925  {
        var fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.28) + 779.75)}
    else if taxable < 3925 && taxable >= 1677  {
        var fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.25) + 217.75)}
    else if taxable < 1677 && taxable >= 484  {
        var fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.15) + 38.80)}
    else if taxable < 484 && taxable >= 96  {
        var fedIncome = (taxable * 0.1)}
    else {
        var fedIncome:Float = 0.0}
     Label.text = ("\(fedIncome)")
}
```

Comment: Your code would benefit greatly from using a `switch` statement with ranges, rather than an `if`/`else if`/`else` block

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnot create the variable inside the `if else` block.

Try moving the declaration outside the if else and change the value inside the `if else` block.

Answer (score 1):

All your lines that assign to `fedIncome` are assigning to a local `var` that you're defining inside the scope of an `if` block. As soon as that block ends, the `fedIncome` variable is deleted and thus is not printed.

As it appears above, your example doesn't seem as if it should compile at all. If it's compiling, my assumption is that your class has a `fedIncome` property defined somewhere else, and your `print` statement is printing that instead of the value you just calculated.

Anyway, declare `fedIncome` outside of the `if` statements, and get rid of the `var` statement within the `if` statements, and you should solve your problem. You may also consider converting the `var`s to `let` instead, since you're not mutating them after you set them.

Answer (score 0):

Ya it is because you are declaring federal income as a local variable inside each of the if / else statements. Try something like this:

```
@IBAction func ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let hourly = 9.00
    let hours = 61.75
    let exemptions = 1.00
    let deductions = 95.80
    let allowances = (exemptions * deductions)
    let gross = (hourly * hours)
    let taxable = (gross - allowances)
    var fedIncome:Float = 0.0 // default value
    if taxable >= 17529 {
        fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.396) + 5062.69)}
    else if taxable < 17529 && taxable >= 17458  {
        fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.35) + 5037.84)}
    else if taxable < 17458 && taxable >= 8081  {
        fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.33) + 1943.43)}
    else if taxable < 8081 && taxable >= 3925  {
        fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.28) + 779.75)}
    else if taxable < 3925 && taxable >= 1677  {
        fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.25) + 217.75)}
    else if taxable < 1677 && taxable >= 484  {
        fedIncome = ((taxable * 0.15) + 38.80)}
    else if taxable < 484 && taxable >= 96 {
        fedIncome = (taxable * 0.1)}
    }

    Label.text = ("\(fedIncome)")
}
```

Notice that fedIncome is declared at the top with the other variables local to the function, and then each if / else just updates it accordingly...

Comment: You should declare `fedIncome` with `let`, not `var`.

Comment: @rmaddy not if you want to update it like shown above...

Comment: If you change the declaration to `let fedIncome: Float` then it will work.

Comment: @rmaddy true but this way he could also initialize with a default value that is more explicit than the last else statement, and also remove the last else. Why would declaring a constant here be better in your mind?

Comment: Because ultimately it is a constant. It just happens to be assigned its value conditionally.

Comment: Interesting, I see your point. I guess everything up there should be a constant then, but I still like the idea of explicit initialization...

Answer (score 0):

Place the `var fedIncome` along with the rest of the variables before you enter the *if* statements.. so when a condition in either of the if statements is true, the change applied to the `fedIncome` is not reset once you exit the *if* block